# Exporting variables in bash

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, export, ls

I have a script in bash that I am trying to use to count the number of directories and total number of files within a certain directory.  This directory is defined on the command line and exported like so:

```
export ARCHIVE= "/home/wpz23/CS265/assign1/testfiles"
```

Then it is used in the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash

files= $(find "$ARCHIVE"  -type d -or -type f | grep -v '^.$' | wc -l)

sub= $(ls -lR "$ARCHIVE" | grep ^d | wc -l)

awk '{ print $sub $files }'
```

For some reason the script cannot find the directory and it comes up as blank when I try to pass it into the script and I am not sure why.  Here are the error messages I get:

```
find: cannot search `': No such file or directory
./prob1: line 9: 0: command not found
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
./prob1: line 11: 0: command not found
```

I am rather new to scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the space after the `=` in that `export` line. It is incorrect. That `awk` command also is not being given any input.

Comment: Ok That works now. How would I modify the `awk` command?

Comment: Are you just using that to print the shell variables? Because that isn't going to work like that (shell variables aren't expanded in single quotes). Why not just use `echo "$sub $files"`? or `printf '%s %s\n' "$sub" "$files"`?

Comment: You can paste your script in www.shellcheck.net There are few repeated errors: `var= $(command)` is wrong, you need to remove the space like @EtanReisner said. Also, `awk '{print $sub}'` does not work: you need to pass the variable to awk with `-v` ---> `awk -v myvar="$sub" '{print myvar}' file`